# Display values from form submission to a DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am a learner of ReactJs. I have a fully functional form in ReactJS made with hooks. I've some fields and I just want to display my form submitted data to a DOM when handleSubmit is clicked.

I want the user to add any number of forms as it works and display all of those submitted data below.

Here is codesandbox code. [Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-oskar-mwfqo)

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippets here even if you link to a third party provider

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've attempted to use the array as an object, you should first indicate the array index, in your case it is 0 and that will give you access to the array first element which is your object and now you could get the values from it

```
let val = [...fields]
// when you want access the data
val[0].name
```

This is the bug in your code if I've got you correctly